# How to select a specific folder from Google Drive and upload a file into it?

Tags: google-apps-script

As i m trying to upload a file into a specific folder,but i can not find an object which can select a specified folder from Drive,

as i tried here...

```
function doGet(e){
 var app=UiApp.createApplication();
var panel=app.createHorizontalPanel();
var month1=app.createListBox().addItem("January").addItem("Febuary").addItem("March").setId("month12").setName("month12");
var upload=app.createFileUpload().setName("file");
var uploadbutton=app.createSubmitButton("UPLOAD");
panel.add(month1).add(upload).add(uploadbutton);

var form=app.createFormPanel();
form.add(panel);
app.add(form);
return app;
 }

   function doPost(e){
  var app=UiApp.createApplication();

 var month=e.parameter.month12;
 var file=e.parameter.file; //user upload fileName

 var files = DriveApp.getFolders();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var fileName=file.getName();

  if(month==fileName){
    var doc = DocsList.createFile(file);  //that directly uploaded into the Drive List       
    Logger.log("inside");
    }
  }

return app;
 }
```

DocsList directlly upladed a file into the Drive,if i use DriveApp.CreateFolder then it is creating a folder into the drive.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because UiApp service is deprecated. Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/54605042/1595451

Answer (score 0):

Try using the (folder).createfile("file") instead of the  DocList function. i.e.

```
var folder = DocsList.getFolder("MyFolder");

var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(e.parameter.file); // process blob ready to save 
var doc = folder.createFile(fileBlob); // createfile in specified folder
```

Comment: here "MyFolder" is the folder in the Drive,actually it is not working its showing "unexpected error occured"

Comment: yea its working now...thanks...i had to remove that `utilities`.
it start working..what if we want to set the autherisation..aur other user wanted to upload